# Windows 10 Mouse Freezes Temporarily (like for 5 seconds) when hovering over images / hyperlinks

Tags: windows-10

I started using windows 10 after a long time. It has been a very very painful and frustrating experience so far. This thing is a piece of garbage.

So what I notice is that the mouse (I have a lenovo 530 and am using the trackpad) pointer freezes for 5 seconds when I hover over an image or a hyperlink.

I have already tried

** update all lenovo drivers including the track pad.
** found all processes in task manager related to trackpad and ensured that they are running in compatibility mode of windows 7.
** re-installed the device driver
** re-booted my machine

This thing has no end to misery. I have 32 GB ram on my machine and am running 64 bit OS.

Comment: Did you monitor CPU usage as this is probably where the bottleneck occurs?

Comment: I observed the system for some time. Although there is no spike ... the `synaptic touchpad 64 bit enhancements` process does move up in CPU utilization when it gets stuck

Comment: If the system is otherwise not using much CPU, this would likely indicate a bug in the driver.

Comment: yeah that is obvious. what do I do about it?

Comment: Go to the manufacturer's forums and see if others are already talking about it, otherwise start a new thread.

Comment: Do you have antivirus installed?